# Which algorithm could i use to determine which series of actions led to the current state?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary containing names (that change) and static IDs as follows:

```
names = {
"A" : "01",
"B" : "02",
"C" : "03",
"D" : "04"
}
```

and i have a dictionary containing name changes as follows:

```
history = [
{"new": "A", "old": "W"},
{"new": "B", "old": "Y"},
{"new": "Y", "old": "X"},
{"new": "C", "old": "S"},
{"new": "D", "old": "C"},
{"new": "C", "old": "F"}
]
```

The changes at the bottom are those that occurred first chronologically, and no 2 objects can have the same name at the same time.

What i want to do is label these changes with the static ID of the final name. In the above dictionary of changes it would look like this:

```
output = {
"01":{"new": "A", "old": "W"},
"02":{"new": "B", "old": "Y"},
"02":{"new": "Y", "old": "X"},
"03":{"new": "C", "old": "S"},
"04":{"new": "D", "old": "C"},
"04":{"new": "C", "old": "F"}
}
```

This is what i tried to setup (it doesn't work!):

```
def solveRecursively(change, names, history):
    new = change["new"]
    old = change["old"]

    hasAnotherNameChange = False
    otherNameChange = None

    for otherChange in history:
        if otherChange.get("old") == new and (not the same change):
            hasAnotherNameChange = True
            otherNameChange = otherChange
    
    if hasAnotherNameChange:
        return handle_name_change(otherNameChange, names, history)
    elif new in names:
        return names[new]
    else:
        return None

output = {}
for change in history:
    ID = solveRecursively(change, names, changes)
    output[ID] = change
```

What it does is for every change it checks to see if there is a change that occurred where the current name (new) is in the OLD field of that other change.

It runs into an infinite loop in the following case:

```
history = {
{"new": "A", "old": "X"},
{"new": "X", "old": "A"},
{"new": "A", "old": "X"}
}
```

Every other approach i have tried just gets stuck on an edge case. I feel like there has to be some kind of algorithm or data structure appropriate for this problem. A graph or tree or something but i am completely stumped.

Sidenote: Each change has a unique ID so it's possible to avoid comparing to the same object and they are sorted in reverse chronological order (latest at the top, earliest at the bottom).

Comment: The problem is that you always consider the full history in your loop. At some point in your loop, you're already "back" in time, so you should make the recursive call with a truncated history, containing only the change name events that occured before the name change currently considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do this.

First create a dataframe from `history` and add a new column with `names`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(history)

df['key'] = df['new'].map(names)
df['key'] = df['key'].ffill()  # fill NaN value with previous row value
```

```
# print(df)

  new old key
0   A   W  01
1   B   Y  02
2   Y   X  02
3   C   S  03
4   D   C  04
5   C   F  03
```

Then `apply()` the function by row to construct with desired format.

```py
out = df.apply(lambda row: {row['key']: {'new': row['new'], 'old': row['old']}}, axis=1).tolist()
```

```
# from pprint import pprint
# pprint(out)

[{'01': {'new': 'A', 'old': 'W'}},
 {'02': {'new': 'B', 'old': 'Y'}},
 {'02': {'new': 'Y', 'old': 'X'}},
 {'03': {'new': 'C', 'old': 'S'}},
 {'04': {'new': 'D', 'old': 'C'}},
 {'03': {'new': 'C', 'old': 'F'}}]
```

Your desired output is a dict with same key. However, duplicate key in dictionary is not allowed in Python. So I just give you a list of dict.